# Using Mocha/Chai, how can I test a function without actually running it?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

This may be a simple question, but I have a function that writes to a config function when called. I don't want to write to the config function from the test suite, so how do I approximate this with Mocha/Chai tests? Before/after hooks won't work because those just wait until after the function runs, right? Do I have to use stubs? New to this testing framework, thanks for any help!

Comment: yes, stub is definitely something you're looking for. If you provide you codebase we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I don't know for certain but it might be possible to make a dummy config function just for the test and have your test suite run that

also... before runs before every test and after runs after every test. This way you can setup before each test and cleanup after each test